# Symfony API search for localized products

Tags: symfony, doctrine, api-platform.com

Sorry if the title is not clear I don't know how to say it.

I use doctrine translatable to translate a Product in different languages like `fr` and `en`.
And I want to add a basic search functionality to the product using `ApiPlatform`
The problem is I don't know how to add a custom Search Filter or Query Collection Extension to search a product based on name field since I don't have a relationship with the translatable entity directly. It may not be clear so let me show the code:

I have a basic `Product`:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\GetCollection;
use App\Repository\ProductRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\Contract\Entity\TranslatableInterface;
use Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\Model\Translatable\TranslatableTrait;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: ProductRepository::class)]
#[ApiResource(
    operations: [
        new GetCollection(
            normalizationContext: ['groups' => ['Product:collection', 'read']],
        ),
    ],
)]
class Product implements TranslatableInterface
{
    use TranslatableTrait;

    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    #[Groups('read')]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    #[Groups(['Product:collection'])]
    private ?int $price = null;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getPrice(): ?int
    {
        return $this->price;
    }

    public function setPrice(int $price): self
    {
        $this->price = $price;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

And `ProductTranslation`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\ProductTranslationRepository;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\Contract\Entity\TranslationInterface;
use Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\Model\Translatable\TranslationTrait;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: ProductTranslationRepository::class)]
class ProductTranslation implements TranslationInterface
{
    use TranslationTrait;

    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $name = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::TEXT, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $description = null;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDescription(): ?string
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function setDescription(?string $description): self
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

The goal is to do some `/products?search_terms=foo` and based on the request locale search a product with the `name` field inside `ProductTranslation` class.

Have someone tried to do it or a better alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed! someone had same problem and the solution is here https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors/issues/674

```php
<?php

namespace App\ApiPlatform;

use ApiPlatform\Doctrine\Orm\Extension\QueryCollectionExtensionInterface;
use ApiPlatform\Doctrine\Orm\Util\QueryNameGeneratorInterface;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\Operation;
use App\Entity\Product;
use Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder;

class QueryCollectionExtension implements QueryCollectionExtensionInterface
{
    public function applyToCollection(QueryBuilder $queryBuilder, QueryNameGeneratorInterface $queryNameGenerator, string $resourceClass, Operation $operation = null, array $context = []): void
    {
        if ($resourceClass === Product::class) {
            $searchTerms = $context['filters']['search_terms'] ?? null;

            if (null !== $searchTerms && '' != $searchTerms) {
                $alais = $queryBuilder->getRootAliases()[0];

                $queryBuilder->join(sprintf('%s.translations', $alais), 'p_tr')
                    ->andWhere('p_tr.name LIKE :terms')
                    ->setParameter('terms', '%' . $searchTerms . '%')
                ;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciated that you share your answer! Could you please accept your own answer, please?

Comment: Ok, I accepted.